# How can I give a file extension from a tuple?

Tags: django

I'm a beginner in django
I need to give the file a name and extension when saving the file
I now have :

```
def generate_filename(instance, filename):
    filename = instance.title + '.pdf'
    return "{0}/{1}".format(instance, filename)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Name')
```

this assigns the file the name title and the extension pdf
Then I wrote a tuple:

```
FORMAT = (
    (1, 'PDF'),
    (2, 'FB2'),
    (3, 'EPUB'),
    (4, 'MOBI'),  
    (5, 'TXT'),
    (6, 'DJVU'),
    (7, 'DOC'),
    (8, 'ZIP'),
    (9, 'RAR'),
)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Name')
    formate = models.IntegerField(choices=FORMAT, default=1, db_index=True, verbose_name='Format file')
```

If I try to do:

```
filename = instance.title + '.' + formate
```

then I get an error:

```
name 'formate' is not defined
```

I can't figure out how to do it

update
views.py:

```
class BookDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
 model = Book
 template = 'booklist/book_detail.html'
```

ObjectDetailMixin:

```
class ObjectDetailMixin:
 model = None
 template = None
 detail_admin_panel = None

 def get(self, request, **kwargs):
     obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug=kwargs['slug'])


     context = {
         self.model.__name__.lower(): obj,
         'categories': Category.objects.all(),
     }

     return render(request, self.template, context=context)
```

the code is not mine, I don't even quite understand how it works

Comment: Are you asking how to access an attribute from inside a method?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, my English is at zero, and that's probably what I want to know

Comment: Please post your relevant code from your views.py